# Trying to Populate a Column with a Query

Tags: sql-server

So I'm doing a data mining project for one of my classes. As part of it, I'm trying to apply Min Max Normalization to some of the data- which is the easy part. The hard part had been actually inserting the results of the queries into the table.

At first, I tried an INSERT INTO statement...

```
insert into dbo.CountsA([TotalCountMinMAx])
SELECT
1.00*(TotalCount-MinCount)/CountRange as TotalCountMinMax
FROM
(
SELECT
   TotalCount,
   MIN(TotalCount) OVER () AS MinCount,
   MAX(TotalCount) OVER () - MIN(TotalCount) OVER () AS CountRange
FROM
   dbo.CountsA
) X
```

The subquery itself works fine, but the moment I tried inserting the results into the table, it only inserted a number of null records. So instead of, say, updating ten entries in the TotalCountMinMAx column, it created ten additional records, and set all the columns to NULL.

After busting my head trying to figure that out, I tried using an UPDATE query instead.

```
update dbo.CountsA
set [TotalCountMinMAx]=(
SELECT
1.00*(TotalCount-MinCount)/CountRange as TotalCountMinMax
FROM
(
SELECT
   TotalCount,
   MIN(TotalCount) OVER () AS MinCount,
   MAX(TotalCount) OVER () - MIN(TotalCount) OVER () AS CountRange
FROM
   dbo.CountsA
) X)
```

This query failed to run entirely.

"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

At this point, short of digging out my old SQL book and basically relearning SQL from scratch (I am very, very rusty), I'm out of ideas for making either of these codes work.

Comment: killed `mysql` tag due to .dbo spotting

Answer (score 0):

In case 1, when you insert, data will add row below old data. Example, if your table like:

```
ID | Col
1     2
2     4
```

After you insert just only Col column values: 3,4
Your table like this:

```
ID | Col
1     2
2     4
NULL  3
NULL  4
```

In case 2:
IF you use sub-query to insert like:

```
UPDATE Your_Table
SET Col = (<sub-query>)
```

sub-query must return a single value.

You can add where clause make sub-query return a single value, like this:

```
UPDATE Your_Table
SET Col = (SELECT ... FROM Your_Table) AS A
WHERE Col_ID = A.Col_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not **correlating** your `sub-query` that's the reason to get *Sub-query retuned more than one row error*.

Try using `CTE` to update which is easy and more readable.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT 1.00 * ( TotalCount - MinCount ) / CountRange AS TotalCountMinMax_N,
                TotalCountMinMax
         FROM   (SELECT TotalCount,
                        TotalCountMinMax,
                        Min(TotalCount)
                          OVER ()             AS MinCount,
                        Max(TotalCount)
                          OVER () - Min(TotalCount)
                                      OVER () AS CountRange
                 FROM   dbo.CountsA) X)
UPDATE cte
SET    TotalCountMinMax = TotalCountMinMax_N
```